# Remove extra new line in XML generated by Jdom2

Tags: java, xml, jdom-2

I used `getPrettyFormat()` in Jdom2 and it gives me a XML file as below.

```
<startDate>2016-05-27</startDate>

<endDate>2021-05-27</endDate>

<enrollBeginDate>2016-05-27</enrollBeginDate>

<enrollEndDate>2016-05-27</enrollEndDate>
```

But I need to remove the additional new line between tags. So the output should like below;

```
<startDate>2016-05-27</startDate>
<endDate>2021-05-27</endDate>
<enrollBeginDate>2016-05-27</enrollBeginDate>
<enrollEndDate>2016-05-27</enrollEndDate>
```

My code;

```
Document xmlMessage = new Document(eleCourse);
XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat().setOmitDeclaration(true).set);
return xmlOutput.outputString(xmlMessage);
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried the `.setTextMode(Format.TextMode.PRESERVE))` (linked it after `.getPrettyFormat()`)

Comment: It may well be a carriage-return/newline CR/NL thing